# How to avoid calculating mean when grouping variable is missing?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the mean of a data frame column based on a grouping variable, and I want the calculated variable to be missing when the grouping variable is missing. The desired outcome is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~data, ~id_avg,
  "a", 1,     1.5,
  "a", 2,     1.5,
  NA,  4,     NA,
  "b", 5,     5
)
```

I have tried the following:

1.

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(id_avg = mean(data))
```

Does not yield NA in id_avg when id is missing.

2.

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(id_avg =
           if_else(!is.na(id),
                   mean(data),
                   NA)
         )
```

Yields the following error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `id_avg`.
ℹ `id_avg = if_else(!is.na(id), mean(data), NA)`.
x `false` must be a double vector, not a logical vector.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: id = "a".

Comment: The 2nd attempt would work if you replace `NA` with `NA_real_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the *NA* after the mean

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    id_avg = mean(data),
    id_avg = if_else(is.na(id),NA_real_,id_avg)
    )
```

Comment: Yup, you typed the answer faster than I did, but that's exactly what I was going to suggest. It's the most elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for condition in `if`/`else` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(id_avg = if(all(is.na(id))) NA else mean(data)) %>%
  ungroup

#  id     data id_avg
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a         1    1.5
#2 a         2    1.5
#3 NA        4   NA  
#4 b         5    5
```